# Human tracking path planning method

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have started a human tracking project.  I have already the position of the `Target Person` to follow (by LIDAR and Radio). Now,I am searching the "best" way to generate a trajectory (or a velocity command). As far as I understood the `Artificial Potential Field` could be a logic candidate and I do not need to use the [nav stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). I am searching a simple and easy to implement method which has certain robustness level too.

I would appreciate your thoughts about this. Do you propose another method?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281131/human-tracking-path-planning-method/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-01-30**:
Sorry for the noise but I wonder what you are using for Lidar & Radio tracking of a person.

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2018-02-01**:
You can start with the [leg_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector) package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We really need to know what sort of environment this will be operated in and what type of platform will be following the human in order to help you with this. It is a UAV flying through a jungle or a turtle bot driving through an office for example?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2018-01-30**:
Thanks a lot @PeteBlackerThe3rd for your answer.
Our platform is a Differential Wheeled Robot. We would like that the robot follows the operator in outdoor environment (for example an agriculture field).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-02-02**:
Okay, I've got a good idea now. The route planning is the easy part of this, the hard part is perceiving the terrain so you can determine were is safe/dangerous/impossible for your robot. Next question, how are you mapping your environment?